# how to write this piece of code in aspx page

Tags: events, button, onclientclick

Is it possible to write this line in aspx page on button client click event.

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", string.Format("postback(\"{0}\", \"\"); return false;", buttonSave.UniqueID));
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: button id that is rendered in aspx page  is ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$MainContent$btnSave ...i used button.id to get the id in javascript but it gives me ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_MainContent_btnExcel (when i render id as autoid) how can I get the unique id in javascript or may be I can render the aspx id in a different way. Any thoughts? At the moment I am just using the work around by hard coding the id in javascript

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link christian..can u throw some light on the question I asked.